# Delphi, error :"Access violation at address xxxxxxxx. Read of address yyyyyyyy", at AdoQuery.SQL.Text:='''

Tags: sql, delphi

> "Access violation at address xxxxxxxx. Read of address yyyyyyyy"

On this project i have more than 200 procedures like that, but only this procedure gets error (only windows xp)..

Procedure than have error :

```
Procedure TfMain.CreateNewDocument(p_money_direction,p_status,p_base:integer);
begin
  With fMain.ADOTemp  do
  Begin
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO documents '+
              '(document_date,fk_id_status,money_direction,'+
              'paid,addition,saving,fk_id_base,fk_id_user)'+
              'VALUES '+
              '(CONVERT(DATE,:pdocument_date,103),:pfk_id_status,'+
              ':pmoney_direction,0,0,0,:pfk_id_base,:pfk_id_user)';
    Parameters.ParamByName('pdocument_date').Value:=Date;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_status').Value:=p_status;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pmoney_direction').Value:=p_money_direction;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_base').Value:=p_base;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_user').Value:=fMain.ApplicationVariablers.user_id;
    ExecSQL;
  End;
end;
```

Error at :

```
    SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO documents '+
              '(document_date,fk_id_status,money_direction,'+
              'paid,addition,saving,fk_id_base,fk_id_user)'+
              'VALUES '+
              '(CONVERT(DATE,:pdocument_date,103),:pfk_id_status,'+
              ':pmoney_direction,0,0,0,:pfk_id_base,:pfk_id_user)';
```

Debuingging process, error at line 1907 :

[image: print screen]

Comment: Providing the real error message could have helped. Why keep it from us?

Comment: @David, it was on the linked screenshot and says something related to Visual C++ runtime...

Comment: I don't think we have enough info to say why your code fails in msvcrt.dll. why is it even there?

Comment: sometimes error like that, but on same step, http://oi44.tinypic.com/fjkx7k.jpg

Comment: With probability close to 1 your problem does not lie in the code in the question. You'll need to do some debugging to narrow it down.

Comment: I create AdoTemp queary on runtime, http://oi43.tinypic.com/v78odg.jpg, error at line : 1912

Comment: You have some nice memory leaks there, always cleanup what you create... What is bugging me is that the code in the screenshot is not the same as in your question (it omits the line where you create the TAdoQuery)

Comment: my friends, I changed some code, but problem is same problem..

Comment: @user3004668 Well, what code did you change? Just telling us you changed some code is meaningless to us. We cannot read your mind or see your screen.

Comment: Error at line : 1912 on picture : http://oi43.tinypic.com/v78odg.jpg

Comment: well your code is a disaster bound to happen, all I am seeing is references to tempvar this, tempform that. You'll need to read about SOLID principle and isolate your datalayer from your GUI layer, the Database routines should not know about a TempForm and that sort of stuff. And I repeat, your last code change introduces a nasty memory/resource leak...

Comment: Did you read my most recent comment? Do you think I am wrong? If I am right, then the onus on fixing this falls to you.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I cannot see any differences, and nor can I see any memory leaks

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: read the first line of CreateNewDocument function : http://oi43.tinypic.com/v78odg.jpg? I don't see any ADOTemp1.Free statement...

Comment: @David - he is referring to the code in TinyPics, I think

Comment: @HughJones Oh, off-site links that are hidden away in the comments. Ho hum. That just looks like trial and error code that has been left lying around. Memory leaks don't really seem likely to be the problem.

Comment: Can"t anyone solve this problem? (

Comment: As it stands only you can solve it. Good luck.

Comment: Try this - put a break on the line `with fMain.ADOTemp do` and then examine the variables `fMain` and `ADOTemp` and see what that yields.

Comment: @David - no you are right - it looks like an access violation to me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem like that

```
Procedure TfMain.CreateNewDocument(p_money_direction,p_id_status,p_id_base:integer);
Var
  ADOTemp:TAdoQuery;
begin
  ADOTemp:=TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  ADOTemp.Connection:=fMain.ADOConnection;

  With ADOTemp  do
  Begin
    SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('INSERT INTO documents');
      SQL.Add('(document_date,fk_id_status,money_direction,');
      SQL.Add('paid,addition,saving,fk_id_base,fk_id_user)');
      SQL.Add('VALUES ');
      SQL.Add('(CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103),:pfk_id_status,:pmoney_direction,');
      SQL.Add('0,0,0,'+IntToStr(p_id_base)+',:pfk_id_user)');

    Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_status').Value:=p_id_status;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pmoney_direction').Value:=p_money_direction;
    //Parameters.ParamByName('p').Value:=p_id_base;
    Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_user').Value:=fMain.ApplicationVariablers.user_id;
    ExecSQL;
  End;
end;
```

I removed **Parameters.ParamByName('p').Value:=p_id_base;** and it worked

http://oi43.tinypic.com/dvotxx.jpg

But it is not good solition

Comment: There is a memory leak in this code; you need to add a `ADOTemp.Free`  - preferably as part of a `try .. finally`

Answer (score -2):

As first, change assigment for text property using "add" insthead .text.
Using text is not good. some year ago I've issue uisng text property for a complex sql statement.
Also, I suggest you:
FORGET WITH STATEMENT.
Each time I works on code using "with" I spend (waste) more more time to understand code.

```
With fMain.ADOTemp  do
  Begin
    AdoTemp.SQL.Clear;
    AdoTemp.SQL.Add( ' INSERT INTO documents ');
    AdoTemp.SQL.Add( ' (document_date,fk_id_status,money_direction, ');
    ....
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this addresses the issue in the question? All you've done is suggested an alternative way to write the code that will result in identical runtime behaviour. Please concentrate on answering the question that was asked. If you don't know the answer, please feel no obligation to submit an answer.

Comment: I had some strange random error using "sql.text :=  ...." with Ado. I solved using more statements "sql.Add(..)'.

Comment: Sorry, but it not work too? http://oi40.tinypic.com/5knigw.jpg Error at line : 1917

Comment: If I comment 'SQL.Add(':pmoney_direction,0,0,0,:pfk_id_base,:pfk_id_user)');' it returns error like http://oi42.tinypic.com/2w5lys9.jpg that everyone knows (parameter error)