# Why small changes make "Access violation at address xxx" error on this delphi code?

Tags: t-sql, delphi, access-violation

I have 2 pieces of code :

1. It works normal

```
with ADOTemp  do
begin
  SQL.Clear;

  SQL.Add('INSERT INTO documents');
  SQL.Add('(document_date,fk_id_status,money_direction,');
  SQL.Add('paid,addition,saving,fk_id_base,fk_id_user)');
  SQL.Add('VALUES ');
  SQL.Add('(CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103),:pfk_id_status,:pmoney_direction,');
  SQL.Add('0,0,0,'+IntToStr(p_id_base)+',:pfk_id_user)');

  Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_status').Value := p_id_status;
  Parameters.ParamByName('pmoney_direction').Value := p_money_direction;
  // Parameters.ParamByName('p').Value := p_id_base;
  Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_user').Value := fMain.ApplicationVariablers.user_id;

  ExecSQL;
end;
```

2. It does not work and returns a terrible error

```
with ADOTemp  do
begin
  SQL.Clear;

  SQL.Add('INSERT INTO documents');
  SQL.Add('(document_date,fk_id_status,money_direction,');
  SQL.Add('paid,addition,saving,fk_id_base,fk_id_user)');
  SQL.Add('VALUES ');
  SQL.Add('(CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103),:pfk_id_status,:pmoney_direction,');
  SQL.Add('0,0,0,:p,:pfk_id_user)');

  Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_status').Value := p_id_status;
  Parameters.ParamByName('pmoney_direction').Value := p_money_direction;
  Parameters.ParamByName('p').Value := p_id_base;
  Parameters.ParamByName('pfk_id_user').Value := fMain.ApplicationVariablers.user_id;

  ExecSQL;
end;
```

Error on image, line 1917

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this question is in reference to your earlier question: [Delphi, error :"Access violation at address xxxxxxxx. Read of address yyyyyyyy", at AdoQuery.SQL.Text:='''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048406/delphi-error-access-violation-at-address-xxxxxxxx-read-of-address-yyyyyyyy)

You had added and accepted an answer there along the lines seen in this question. The error message, an AV in msvcrt.dll is indicative of a serious programming error. Perhaps a heap corruption. Perhaps something else. The change you made that stops the error occurring does not really fix the problem. The problem will still be there, lying dormant. You just got (un)lucky that the change you made appeared to fix the problem.

Access violations are not always reproducible. That's just their nature. When you encounter one you need to understand why it happens. Simply using trial and error to re-organise code from a completely different location will never lead to the real solution.

What you should be doing is tracking down the real cause of the problem. Do that, fix it, and either version of the code above will work. This is probably not the answer you are wanting to get. You may very well not want to accept what I say. But, speaking from experience, until you recognise that you have a more serious problem, you will make no headway here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code in the bitmap...I'm pretty sure you access violation is because of what David just said...you have serious Memory problems in your code...Your not freeing your objects...that you are creating...Anytime you pass a nil reference to Owner in a TComponent Constructor...your telling the compiler...that you know what your doing and will free it when your finished with it...Matter of fact good practice is to always free objects that you declare and use exclusively in the scope of your method.

```
procedure TForm1.MyMethod;
var
  a_MyComp: TMyComp;
begin
  a_MyComp := TMyComp.Create(nil);  
  Try
    //use my a_MyComp...
  Finally
    a_MyComp.Free;
  End;
end;
```

Check out your code in CreateNewDocument...you'll notice that your not freeing your AdoTemp.

-Rick

Answer (score 0):

Access violation exceptions (AVs) tell you that you have made a mistake in the memory access of your program. However, the way access violations work: they are unable to guarantee always detecting the error every time you make a mistake. (Sometimes you get **un**-lucky and no access violations are raised, but the mistake is still there causing other things to quietly go wrong inside your application.)

You can think of the memory available to your program being represented as below (where "." means the memory is not allocated to anything, and "A" means the memory is allocated to something within your program: e.g. object, local variable, parameter, machine code).

```
[.......AAA..AAAA.....AA......A...A...........AAA....A.......AA.........AAAAA]
```

Suppose you create some object; this will require memory to be allocated for the object itself. If the object in turn creates child objects, this will also be allocated in memory. (I'll use "O" and "C")

```
                 /-ref--\
[.......AAA..AAAAO....AAC.....A...A.....C.....AAA....A.......AA.........AAAAA]
                 \-ref------------------/
```

Note that within the memory allocated to O, it might hold references to its child objects.

Conversely to the above, whenever an object is destroyed, its memory is deallocated. Let us suppose you have made a mistake in your memory access, and something has destroyed one of O's child objects before O has finished using it.

```
                 /-ref--\
[.......AAA..AAAAO....AAC.....A...A...........AAA....A.......AA.........AAAAA]
                 \-ref------------------/
```

If O now tries to use its second child object, you will get an access violation. However, you might be **un**-lucky and not get an access violation showing your earlier mistake **IF**:

- You destroy O without it trying to do anything to the second child object.
- Or you first create a new object that happens to be allocated in the exact same place the child object was.

The second situation tends to be worse than the first, because every time C2 is used on the assumption that it is the correct child of O: unexpected results are produced and an incorrect values are written in memory. These incorrect values may be important data, or references to other objects (making the problem get worse over time).

> So: Whenever yo do get an access violation, thank your **lucky** stars and **hunt down the root cause of the problem**.

**NB! NB!** I cannot stress the importance of the above enough.

#### Investigating your particular problem

*First note*, when an exception pauses in the debugger, the code usually points to the next line that would have been executed if not for the exception. (This doesn't affect anything here, because the previous line is also `ADOTemp.SQL.Add`; - the point is be prepared to consider the previous line as the cause of an exception - and test to confirm it!)

*Useful tip*: When an exception is thrown within Delphi/Third Party code, it can be useful to build with Debug DCU's or recompile Third Party source with debug information to get closer to the actual line raising the exception. (This can even be useful in situations like this where the error appears to be inside a Microsoft DLL.)

Looking at your screen-shot, the exception is thrown from a brand new instance of `TADOQuery`. Now there really isn't any sensible explanation for a brand new query to be throwing access violations when simply adding text to its SQL query. This strongly implies a corruption problem as described earlier.

One possibility would be another thread interfering with this one. (NOTE: even if your application isn't multi-threaded, the ADO objects do have built-in support for asynchronous operations.) However, I'm going to ignore that possibility *for now* because threading issues tend to be less consistent than you've implied this one is.

So, assuming you have a memory access problem somewhere else that is only manifesting here with a brand new `TADOQuery` (used correctly at least up to the point of the AV) - what other objects are interacting with this query to possibly cause corruption?

```
ADOTemp.Connection := fMain.ADOConnection;
```

There is a very strong possibility that commenting out the above line would also eliminate your access violation. So what are the possible problems:

- `fMain` might have been destroyed prematurely and is now a *dangling pointer* meaning the code to return `ADOConnection` could do any of a number of unexpected things.
- Any of the code backing `fMain.ADOConnection` may be referencing corrupted memory or dangling pointers; this includes the returned connection itself.

  - NOTE: One very common cause of invalid memory access is to have a function such as `GetADOConnection` that does not correctly initialise its `Result`. So in some cases it returns a 'random' address in memory, resulting in all sorts of unexpected behaviour when something tries to use the connection.
- Is your ADOConnection created on a different thread, and being used by multiple threads?
- PS: Don't forget to follow [Rick's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20152144/224704), and make sure you destroy the query when you've finished using it. Who knows, there might be an internal bug in ADO that when it runs out of a particular internal resource (due to queries not being destroyed), that causes ADO to start throwing AVs.

**NOTE**: You should be able to test my theory without altering functionality by simply changing the `ADOTemp.Connection := ...` line. Simply assign a connection string to the query instead of a connection object. However, if that solves (or more correctly stated: *hides*) the problem, please follow my advice, and **hunt down the root cause of the AV**.